# Android pipeline on Thoughtworks GO

Tags: android, ant, pipeline, thoughtworks-go

I am trying to set up a pipeline to run unit and acceptance (cucumber) tests for an Android app with Thoughtworks GO server and agent on a Mac Mini build server with Mavericks.

First thing I need is to run a simple Ant task 'clean debug install test' but the console log result is always the same:

```
BUILD FAILED
/Applications/Go Agent.app/pipelines/DLManager-Android/banyan_dm_integration_test/build.xml:55: sdk.dir is missing. 
Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

I have set up the environmental variables on the machine (Agent) and I can run the very same test on the terminal, but it would appear that GO is not taking the same variables.
Any ideas how to properly set the pipeline on GO to run these tests?

Thanks!

Comment: Solved, I had to create an environment variable for the pipeline by going to Admin-->my pipeline-->Ebvironment Variables tab and point it to my ANDROID_HOME sdk. I was doing that on the configuration of the Ant task instead, now its working propery!

Comment: You can put your solution in an answer so people will know this problem is solved.

Comment: You bet... good point, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was easily solved as my problemas was that I was taking the environmental variables from the agent, and I had to create an environment variable for the pipeline by going to Admin-->my pipeline-->Ebvironment Variables tab and point it to name=ANDROID_HOME value=/Users/Shared/android-sdk/sdk.